# Add Legend to Text Format Fieldset

Tags: 7, forms

I'm working on making a site I maintain WCAG AA compliant. One of the items I'm getting flagged for is "Every FIELDSET element must contain exactly one LEGEND element." This error shows up on every page that has a comment function. It turns out it is due to the Text Format option for the comment body:

[image]

I've tried DMPing `$form` from a `form_alter` hook, but I can't seem to find this field set anywhere, at least it doesn't seem to be in the comment-form form.

The ID of that form Item is `edit-comment-body-und-0-format--2`, which when I check my DPM output, there is an entry in comment-body/0/#format, but it's null.

Where can I add a legend to this field set?

Comment: Do you need to provide the format option to your users? Would it work for you if the option full HTML was applied to all comment bodies?

Comment: Also, I can use template.php to override theme_fieldset to check for that form and add the Legend that way, but that seems kinda hackey to me, and I feel like there should be a better way.

Comment: If I absolutely have to remove it, I could do it that way, however, moderators still need to be able to switch between different content types, and so I couldn't remove it for everyone, thus the site wouldn't be WCAG compliant for all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work like this:

```
function mymodule_process(&$variables, $hook) {
  if($hook == 'comment_wrapper') {
    $variables['content']['comment_form']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']['#post_render'][] = '_mymodule_post_render_fieldset';
  }
}


function _mymodule_post_render_fieldset($content, $element) {
  $your_legend = '$0<legend>Your comment legend</legend>'; // $0 is the full matched string
  return preg_replace('/<fieldset[^>]*>/', $your_legend, $content);
}
```

Care to give this a try?